# Removing data point outside of a specific quantile

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to remove data points above 97.5% and below 2.5%. I created the following parsimonious data set to explain the issue:

```
y <- data.table(a = rep(c("b","d"), each = 2, times = 3), c=rep(c("e","f"),
each = 3, times = 2), seq(1,6))
```

I created the following script to accomplish the task:

```
require(data.table)
y[, trimErr := ifelse(y$V3 < quantile(y$V3, 0.95) & y$V3 > quantile(y$V3, 0.05),y$V3, NA),
by = list(a,c)]
```

I then got 4 warning messages, I will only provide the first warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(y, , `:=`(trimErr, ifelse(y$V3 < quantile(y$V3,  :
  RHS 1 is length 12 (greater than the size (3) of group 1). The last 9 element(s) will be discarded.
```

can you please explain to me what the warning means and how can i modify my code.

Would you suggest a better code to remove the top and bottom 2.5% of the data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're grouping by `a` and `c`, but passing in a vector that is the length of the entire `data.table`, instead of just the data for each group.

You don't need the `y$` inside the `[.data.table` call

```
y[, trimErr:=ifelse(V3 < quantile(V3, 0.95) & V3 > quantile(V3, 0.05),V3, NA),
  by=list(a,c)]
y
#    a c V3 trimErr
# 1: b e  1      NA
# 2: b e  2       2
# 3: d e  3      NA
# 4: d f  4      NA
# 5: b f  5       5
# 6: b f  6      NA
# 7: d e  1      NA
# 8: d e  2       2
# 9: b e  3      NA
#10: b f  4      NA
#11: d f  5       5
#12: d f  6      NA
```